# rsync commands automation

Tags: scripts, rsync, automation

I want to automate multiple rsync commands like below:

1. Execute rsync1
2. Display output of rsync1 in the terminal
3. Ask confirmation if want to continue rsync2
4. Execute rsync2

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
# --progress will show rsync progress in real time
rsync1 --progress source dest

read -p "Proceed? [N/y]: " PROCEED

# default response is "n"
PROCEED=${PROCEED:-"n"}

# convert the response to lower case to make it eiser to test
if [ "${PROCEED,,}" = 'y' ]; then
    echo "Proceeding..."
else
    echo "Stopping"
    # change to exit 0 if you don't want this to be an error condition
    exit 1
fi

rsync2 --progress source dest
```